# Binary Tree - Post Order

Tags: java, binary-tree, postorder

The method below is meant to be a Post Order traversal method, for a binary tree. I have a binary tree that looks like this:

```
Root = 17
Root.left = 4
Root.right = 18
Root.left.right = 8
```

With those values I expected an output of 8, 4, 18, 17, since 4 is the root of 18, and post order is meant to print the roots last; however, I got an output of 4, 8, 18, 17. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
public void postOrder(Node n)
{
    if(n == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    preOrder(n.getLeft());
    preOrder(n.getRight());
    System.out.println(n.getData());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `preOrder` inside `postOrder` which gets you a different output.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't see that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, the code seemed correct, you only have to take care of copy/paste sometimes :)